# Failed to convert argument [obj] for value [null] due to: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String

Tags: json, jackson, micronaut

Micronaut 1.3
Jackson 2.13.1

I am passing the date in the format `'dd.MM.yyyy'`

My class field looks like this

```java
    @JsonInclude
    @Column(name = "moving_date")
    @JsonView(JsonViewSimple.class)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy")
    private LocalDate moving_date;
```

After I make a post request with `'02.06.2022'`, I get an error

```
Failed to convert argument [obj] for value [null] due to: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.time.LocalDate` from String \"02.06.2022\": Failed to deserialize java.time.LocalDate: (java.time.format.DateTimeParseException) Text '02.06.2022' could not be parsed at index 0\n at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]
```

In other classes, where I have similar date fields with a pattern and the same set of annotations, there is no such error.

Can anyone help?

I also wrote custom  and date serializer and deserializer,
but when I enable debugging - the program doesn't hit the breakpoints in any of them and an error occurs immediately.

But if I pass the date in the format

```
yyyy-MM-dd
```

then there is no error and all is well.

As far as I understand, this bug occurs somewhere in the depths of the Micronaut.

Comment: The parsing is done by Jackson not Micronaut. Do you have `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule` dependency declared? See: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, I use Jackson 2.13.1 
and, of course, I can share my dependencies here, if I need it

```'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-xml', version: '2.13.1'```

So, I wrote that this bug is observed only in one place, in a specific class.

It is structured similarly to the other 27 classes where the date is used, and there is no such problem there.

Comment: I can share ```build.gradle``` if you need

Comment: ```build.gradle```
https://ctxt.io/2/AADgUp5GFQ